# Display JavaScript value problems

Tags: php, javascript, dom

I've made an autocomplete (suggestions) field, so when you type you get the suggestions below the field as text. I recostructed the javascript and i've made the text clickable. So when you click a modal comes up (another little dialog).

All i want is to show the text from the suggestions field to the modal.
I'm using $.post("thesuggtest.php") method because i need to get the chosen suggestions text (that will be clicked) and get informations about it in the modal through php & mysql.

This is the main JavaScript that i'm using for that but i got some problems.

```
function showHint(str)
        {
        if (str.length==0)
          { 
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
          return;
          }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            comeon = document.getElementById('comeon');
            document.getElementById('predlozi').innerHTML='<a data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" href="#myMail" class="label ttip_b" title="New messages">' + xmlhttp.responseText + '</a><div class="modal hide fade" id="myMail"><div class="modal-header"><button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button><h3>New messages</h3></div><div class="modal-body"><div id="comeon"></div>' + $.post("thesuggtest.php", { 'suggestion' : xmlhttp.responseText },function(data){comeon.innerHTML(data);console.log('Error:', data);}); + '</div></div>';

            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

I'm using gethint.php file to retrieve the suggestions that match the input value from the field (i get them from an array).
The problem is that i can not echo the text in the modal (dialog).

When i put document.write(data) i'm getting the value echoed but on a blank page.
When i put comeon.innerHTML(data) i'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'innerHTML' of null. I know that this type of error is because it can not find the element comeon and it returns null.
Also i get [object Object] in the modal where the echoed text should be.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you manually doing `XMLHttpRequest` stuff? Why not use a library like jQuery that already handles all that?

Comment: Because i'm not so familiar with that stuff. I just want to pass the suggested value to php and to retrieve informations about it from the database in the modal.

Comment: You're already using jQuery's request stuff when you call `$.post`. You should use it for this stuff too.

Comment: Ok, maybe i will but that won't solve the issue. Can we focus on the main problem ?

Comment: I agree with @Xymostech. It's easier to learn the simple way that jQuery does ajax calls than to learn to do it the manual way.

Comment: Well, I know you want to get your existing code working, but you really won't benefit by fixing what you have now, because you'd be building the house on bad mud. What you really should do is start over using jQuery's ajax functions. It will take you like an hour to learn. You'll save dozens or hundreds of hours later. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Here are some problems I can notice;

```
comeon = document.getElementById('comeon');
```

You don t even use the comeon div but you trying to get it before it is created. You create "comeon" div just under the this line.

```
$.post("thesuggtest.php", { 'suggestion' : xmlhttp.responseText },function(data){comeon.innerHTML(data);console.log('Error:', data);});
```

`$.post` is also a async request so it never return any text you are asking for just requesting it. you should call that some other event click of the `<a data-toggle="modal"` maybe. and this time you will be able to get "comeon" div.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So why when i put document.write(data) instead of comeon.innerHTML(data) it retrieves the text from the $.post but the page is blank (its just the text) ?

Comment: it is probably because comeon div not exists when you try to assign it is innerHTML. Even it exists in the time of document.getElementById('comeon') call you assign a new HTML it parent which cause remove this div from the DOM and create completely new one. If you can explain what you are trying to I can help with more code example.